# linear algebra cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Find all the unit vectors in the plane determined by **u**=(3,0,1) and **v**=(1,-1,1) that are perpendicular to the vector **w**=(1,2,0).

Why can't I solve this using the following method (and what is the best method using the cross product)?

$ \mathbf{y} = a.\mathbf{u} + b.\mathbf{v} \qquad (a,b\in \Bbb{R}) $

**y** gives me any point on the plane.

$ c.\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{y} \qquad (c\in \Bbb{R}) $

Cross product gives me the perpendicular vector.

Find **y** such that a,b solve the above equation then divide by ||**y**|| to get $ \mathbf{\hat y} $. I have tried it 3 times and each time I arrive at the nonsense answer.

Comment: I don't think you need or should use the cross product in this problem, since it's not about a vector simultaneously perpendicular to two other vectors. It's about a vector in the plane that is perpendicular to w, so it's much more straight-forward to use the dot product. Find the (a,b) solutions that satisfay <w,y> = 0. (2) Normalize your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\vec v \times \vec y$ is perpendicular to the plane but $w$ is not thus your condition can’t have solution.

We don't need cross product but dot product.

Indeed note that the genric vector in the plane determined by $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are given by

$$\vec x= a\vec u + b \vec v $$

with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

By perpendicularity condition $\vec x \cdot \vec w=0$ we obtain

$$\vec x \cdot \vec w=0\vec x \cdot \vec w =a\vec u \cdot \vec w+b\vec v \cdot \vec w=0\iff3a-b=0 \iff b=3a$$

thus all vectors in the plane determined by $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ and perpendicular to $\vec w$ are

$$\vec x= a\vec u + 3a \vec v=a(6,-3,4)$$

and the corresponding unit vectors are

$$|\vec x|=a\sqrt{36+9+16}=a\sqrt{61}$$

$$\vec y=\pm \frac{\vec x}{|\vec x|}=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{61}}(6,-3,4)$$

Answer (score 0):

The set of all perpendiculars to $w$ is $A=span\{(2,-1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

$span\{u,v\} \cap A=span\{u+3v\}$.

So $\pm \frac{u+3v}{||u+3v||}$

Comment: Thank for the answer! What method are you using to find the span  of all vectors perpendicular to w and how did you find the intersection between A and span{u,v}?

Comment: Eye balling. But seriously: We are in $\mathbb{R}^3$. There is one, and only one, plane to which $w$ is normal to. Each of the $2$ spanning vectors in $A$ is perpendicular to $w$ by itself, and thus the entire plane $A$ is the unique plain $w$ is normal to. Now, both $u$ and $v$ are not perpendicular on their own to $w$. Hence their span is not $A$! Hence Their intersection must have dimension at most $1$. So you just pick a linear combination of $u,v$ that works and it spans the intersection. Get it?